# Configuration system for non-django python web apps?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, deployment, configuration

Every web application needs some kind of configuration system. The common options that you would want:

- Environments and instances

  - different settings for production/testing/dev/unit testing/etc
  - Some way to selecting the correct environment
- Unit testing

  - different database isolation strategies:

    - persistent database
    - tests happen in transactions
    - database flushed or recreated for each test
  - A guarantee you don't accidentally run tests on wrong settings (by, say, selecting a wrong command line parameters).
- Settings customization for local development
- A way to customize production settings when deployed
- Management commands runner.
- Instances: preset app deployment configurations with their own dev/prod/..., such as the main app, the celery tasks runner, the enterprise version etc.

Now, django does most of these things. It only has one database isolation strategy in unit test runner, but hey. Its system works as a basis, and you can add a bunch of `from some_settings import *` inside the settings module to customize configurations.

However, outside of django I know of no modules that provide that kind of utilites (and no, Flask configuration system does not count). I end up inventing the wheel every time using `import *` or `execfile`.

So, the question is: did I miss anything? Does such a module exists? Or should one be created?